# Error de web (compatibilidad) con dispositivos móviles iPhone

Tags: ionic, iphone

estoy creando una web con Angular e Ionic, se que es poca la información, pero igual necesito de su ayuda, ya que, al probar la web en dispositivos móviles con Android, funciona de maravilla, pero en iPhone en versiones como la 13 pro o 14 plus los textos de los inputs se ven blancos y no se ve el texto dentro, no sé si a alguien de aquí le paso o sabe cómo solucionarlo. No puedo dar mucho más detalle ya que el defecto solo es en los iPhone. Por cierto, la prueba es en crhome.

Comment: Has revisado el archivo "src/theme/variables.scss" allí se ponen estilos específicos para cada plataforma.